# Android linearlayout design problem

Tags: android, layout, android-linearlayout

For my design i have in the xml file something like:

The design is like a row that have two cells. I want one of them to be autosize and fill the row and one of them to have fixez size. I want that the second linearlayout to wrapp its content and the first one to fill the rest of the space.
Something like in css having two divs floating left and one having fixed size and one filling the rest of the row.

Is something like that possible using the xml file without changing the sizes manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your description is pretty confusing, but do you mean something like [this](http://www.curious-creature.org/2009/02/22/android-layout-tricks-1/)?

Also read all the way down until he starts talking about RelativeLayouts. They are generally preferred over LinearLayouts.